# Javascript getting last Friday of month is returning wrong result

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In pure Javascript I'm trying to generate two dates, a `next` and a `following`. I need to generate these dates to be the last friday of the month whereby `next` would be the last friday of the current month *(unless within 7 days of the end of the month and then it'll be the following month)* and the same with `following` just one month ahead of whatever `next` is.

My JS right now has got several helper functions that I've written to extract parts of the logic into reusable parts and is called via my `getPaydates` paydates function.

However, right now my `next` and `following` appear to be wrong, e.g:

```
provided date: 2021-06-01
next: 2021-06-24, following: 2021-07-24 (both wrong)
should be: 2021-06-25 (next) and 2021-07-30 (following)

provided date: 2021-06-25
next: 2021-08-24, following: 2021-10-24 (both wrong)
should be: 2021-07-30 (next) and 2021-08-27 (following)
```

What am I missing in my code? I've got a [JS fiddle reproduction](https://jsfiddle.net/q6bkeaj3/2/) that can be viewed, but I'll also add the code here:

```js
/*
** Get days left in a month
**
**    Get the number of days left in a month
*/

function getDaysLeftInMonth (date) {
  const daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(getCurrentYear(date), getCurrentMonth(date))
  let left = getDateDiffInDays(date, getEndOfMonth(getCurrentYear(date), getCurrentMonth(date)))

  if (left <= 0)  left = 0
  return left
}



/*
** Get Days In Month
**
**    Get the number of days in a given month & year.
*/

function getDaysInMonth (year, month) {

  // January is: 1
  // 0 is the last day of the month
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()
}


/*
** Get end of month
**
**    Get the date for the end of the month
*/

function getEndOfMonth (year, month) {
    const lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0)
  return lastDay
}


/*
** Get Current Year
**
**    Get the current year that we're in.
*/

function getCurrentYear (now = new Date()) {
  return new Date(now).getFullYear()
}


/*
** Get Current Month
**
**    Get the current month that we're in
*/

function getCurrentMonth (now = new Date()) {
  return new Date(now).getMonth()
}


/*
** Add Months to date
**
**    Add months to a date and move date forward
*/

function addMonthsToDate (date = new Date(), months = 0) {
  const d = date.getDate()

  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months)

  if (date.getDate() != d) {
    date.setDate(0)
  }

  return date
}


/*
** Add days to date
**
**   Add days to date and return the date
*/

function addDaysToDate (date = new Date(), days = 0) {
  const today = new Date(date)
  today.setDate(today.getDate() + days)
  return today
}


/*
** Difference between two dates
**
**   Get the difference between two dates
*/

function getDateDiffInDays (start, end) {
  const diffTime = end.getTime() - start.getTime()
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24))

  return diffDays
}


/*
** Last Friday of Month
**
**   Get the last friday of the month where the given year
**   and month is provided
*/

function getLastFridayOfMonth (year, month) {
  let lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0)
  lastDay.setDate(lastDay.getDate() - (lastDay.getDay() + 2) % 7)
  
  return lastDay
}


/*
** Reverse date string
**
**    Reverse date string, assumes already formatted date
*/

function reverseDateStr (str) {
  return str.split('/').reverse().join('/')
}


/*
** Calculate paydates
**
**    Programatically calculate the paydates
*/

function getPaydates (now = new Date()) {
  const month = getCurrentMonth(now)
  const year = getCurrentYear(now)
  const lastFriday = getLastFridayOfMonth(year, month)

  let next = new Date(lastFriday).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  let following = new Date(addMonthsToDate(lastFriday, 1)).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
      
    if (getDaysLeftInMonth(now) <= 7) {
    next = new Date(addMonthsToDate(lastFriday, 1)).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    following = new Date(addMonthsToDate(lastFriday, 2)).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  }

  return {
    next: reverseDateStr(next).split('/').join('-'),
    following: reverseDateStr(following).split('/').join('-')
  }
}

console.log(getPaydates(new Date('2021-06-01')))
```

#### UPDATE

Strangely, if I console log the `next` and `lastFriday` inside of the `getPaydates` function, one result is technically correct whilst the other is a day out?

```js
const lastFriday = getLastFridayOfMonth(year, month)
let next = new Date(lastFriday).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  
console.log(next)       // <--- this should be 2021-06-25 but is a day out
console.log(lastFriday) // <-- why is this correct?
```

Comment: `getLastFridayOfMonth()` is broken e.g. `getLastFridayOfMonth(2021,5)` returns `2021-05-28`... in May instead of June.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's wrong thus why I've opened an issue on Stackoverflow. I've updated my JS fiddle & code above, feel free to reload and see updates

Comment: Can I assume that you simply want to find Friday from next month if last Friday for current month has passed?

Comment: Given a date, find the last Friday of the current & following month, relative to the given date, unless that date is within 7 days of the end of the month and move forward the dates by a month

Comment: Your functions are inconsistent. For *getDaysInMonth*, *month* seems to be calendar month number (Jan = 1), whereas in *getLastFridayOfMonth* and *getEndOfMonth*, *month* seems to be ECMAScript month number (Jan = 0) given `lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0)`.

Comment: `new Date(lastFriday).toISOString()` returns the wrong day because *toISOString* uses the UTC date, so if you're east of Greenwich and the time component of the date is less than the local offset, the date is the previous day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this if meets your needs, you can have a look.

```js
function getPaydates(now = new Date()) {
  // get this firday
  const day = now.getDay() === 0 ? 7 : now.getDay();
  const firday = new Date(now.getTime() + (5 - day) * 1000 * 24 * 3600);
  const week = 7 * 1000 * 24 * 3600;

  let next;
  let following;

  [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    .map((i) => new Date(week * i + firday.getTime()))
    .forEach((date) => {
      if (!following && date.getMonth() === firday.getMonth() + 1)
        following = date;
      if (!next && date.getMonth() === firday.getMonth()) next = date;
    });

  return {
    next: next.toISOString().slice(0, 10),
    following: following.toISOString().slice(0, 10),
  };
}
```

When `now` is '2021-06-01', the `next` is '2021-06-25', the `following` is '2021-07-30', the result is the same as it when `now` is '2021-06-26'. By the way, `Date.toISOString` will have time zone issues.

Comment: Looks good, but I'm sure my current code isn't that far out so I need to utilise that as your proposal is effectively a rewrite of the functions in my system which I can't do.

Comment: Please do not add days by adding multiples of 8.64e7 ms. Where daylight saving is observed, days are not always 24 hours long. Use get/setDate and add days as integers. Consider `let day = now.getDay() || 7`.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, You need to update getLastFridayOfMonth function.

```
function getLastFridayOfMonth (year, month) {      
   let lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
   lastDay.setDate(lastDay .getDate() - (lastDay.getDay() + 2) % 7);
   return lastDay 
}
```

> Secondly. You need to update getPaydates function.

```
function getPaydates (now = new Date()) {
   const month = getCurrentMonth(now)
   const year = getCurrentYear(now)
   const lastFriday = getLastFridayOfMonth(year, month) 
   const followinglastFriday = getLastFridayOfMonth(year, month+1)
      
   return {
        next: lastFriday.getFullYear() + '-' + (lastFriday.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + lastFriday.getDate(),
        following: followinglastFriday.getFullYear() + '-' + (followinglastFriday.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + followinglastFriday.getDate(),
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `currentDateObj` since that's been missed out in your code for the last friday of month? is that meant to be `lastDay`?

Comment: I fixed it. it meant to be lastDay.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `% 7`, I'm not seeing what that's doing here? For June I'm getting returned the 24th, not 25th

Comment: Did you not get the correct result still?

Comment: I'll revise my description's code example and JS fiddle shortly after all these changes

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code and JS fiddle, please reload and view the new edits including results

Comment: I checked okay but you need to remove unused functions. I think

Comment: Okay, so we cannot remove those functions as they are used elsewhere in the project, are you able to reproduce the same results in the JS fiddle? It might be worth editing the JS fiddle with my code in there and linking back a link

Comment: Because toISOString() ignore timezone offset, I think

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's related, how can I get back a date string format od `YYYY-MM-DD` without this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems overly convoluted, consider reducing it to  just what's needed, then replace parts with library functions if it makes sense. There's no need to wrap a function around *date.getMonth*.

The following is a simplified version that returns the last Friday of the current month, or of the next month if the passed date is within 7 days of the end of the month, plus the last Friday of the following month.

Some functions are simplified, those that aren't used or are unnecessary have been omitted. *getLastOfDay* is a general function to get the last of the specified day in the month, so can be used for any day of the week.

```js
// Get last day of month
function getEOM (date) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
}
 
// Return last of specified day in month of date
// ECMAScript day numbering: 0 = Sun, 1 = Mon, etc.
function getLastOfDay(date, day) {
  // Get eom
  let lastDay = getEOM(date);
  // Set to last of specified day
  lastDay.setDate(lastDay.getDate() - ((lastDay.getDay() + (7-day)) % 7));
  return lastDay;
}

// Add months to Date
function addMonths(date, months) {
  let d = new Date(date);
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + Number(months));
  // If new day not equal to old day then have overshot end of
  // month, so set d to end of previous month
  if (d.getDate() != date.getDate()) {
    d.setDate(0);
  }
  return d;
}

/* Return last Friday of current month and next. If passed date
 * is less than 7 days from end of month, return last Friday
 * of next and following months.
 *
 * @param {Date} date - date to use to get Fridays
 * @returns {Object} - {next: {Date}, following: {Date}
 */
function getFridays(date) {
  let eom = getEOM(date);
  // If date is within 7 days of eom, increment month
  if (eom.getDate() - date.getDate() < 7) {
    eom = addMonths(eom, 1);
  }
  // Get next Friday
  let next = getLastOfDay(eom, 5);
  // Get following Friday
  let following = getLastOfDay(addMonths(eom, 1), 5);
  return {next, following};
}

// Examples
[new Date(2021,3, 1), // 1 Apr 2021 - more than 7 days from EOM
 new Date(2021,3,24), // 24 Apr 2021 - less than 7 days from EOM
 new Date(2021,3,30), // 30 Apr 2021 - Friday at EOM
 new Date(2021,5,23), // 23 Jun 2021 - 7 days from EOM
 new Date()           // Current date
].forEach(d => {
  let result = getFridays(d);
  console.log(
    'Input     : ' + d.toDateString() +
    '\nNext      : ' + result.next.toDateString() +
    '\nFollowing : ' + result.following.toDateString()
  );
});
```